# Deserialization of JSON-Value

Tags: objective-c, json

I have problems with deserialization of a JSON-Value.

Here is my Code:

```
NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options:0 error: &errorJson];
NSString *innerJson = responseDict[@"d"];
NSMutableDictionary *innerObject = [innerJson JSONValue];
```

As you can see in the fallowing printscreen (which is taken right after executing the last line of the code above), the items in the dictionary innerObject contains special characters, which are not there in innerJson. Can someone help me, why this occurs?

[image]

**edit - added Descriptions of the variables from console**

*innerJson:*

```
{"ret" : "1",  "msg" : "",  "list" : ["Granatapfel¤200g¤1", "Brombeeren¤300g¤1", "Papaya (100 g)¤3¤0", "EPF Müesli 1 Messlöffel¤2¤1", "grüner Spargel (190 g)¤2¤1", "Chicorée (130 g)¤1¤0", "mageres Kalbfleisch (190 g)¤3¤0", "Zander (160 g)¤6¤0", "Bachsaibling (190 g)¤2¤0", "Seeteufel (160 g)¤1¤0", "EPF Guetzli Hafer/\nKartoffel-Dinkel 3 Stk.¤0¤0"]}
```

*innerObject:*

```
{
    list =     (
        "Granatapfel\U00a4200g\U00a41",
        "Brombeeren\U00a4300g\U00a41",
        "Papaya (100 g)\U00a43\U00a40",
        "EPF M\U00fcesli 1 Messl\U00f6ffel\U00a42\U00a41",
        "gr\U00fcner Spargel (190 g)\U00a42\U00a41",
        "Chicor\U00e9e (130 g)\U00a41\U00a40",
        "mageres Kalbfleisch (190 g)\U00a43\U00a40",
        "Zander (160 g)\U00a46\U00a40",
        "Bachsaibling (190 g)\U00a42\U00a40",
        "Seeteufel (160 g)\U00a41\U00a40",
        "EPF Guetzli Hafer/\nKartoffel-Dinkel 3 Stk.\U00a40\U00a40"
    );
msg = "";
ret = 1;
```

}

Comment: Never trust the debugger.  Do `po innerObject` in the console and see what you get.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I have addes the descriptions from the console to the question. Can you help me with this additional informations?

Comment: What's the encoding you are using in your `data` object?

Comment: @iska - it's utf-8: [request setValue: @"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField: @"content-type"];

Comment: @ThomasKehl: The description method of NSDictionary prints all non-ASCII characters as `\Unnnn` escape sequence, so `\U00a4` is the same as `¤`. I can therefore not see anything in "innerObject" that is not present in "innerJson".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see a problem with your JSON value. The `description` method of `NSString` 
prints all Unicode characters verbatim, e.g.

```
"Granatapfel¤200g¤1"
```

On the other hand, the `description` method of `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` prints all non-ASCII characters
as a `\Unnnn` escape, e.g. `\U00a4` instead of `¤`:

```
"Granatapfel\U00a4200g\U00a41"
```

If you extract the string values from `innerObject`, e.g.

```
NSString *s = innerObject["list"][0];
NSLog(@"%@", s);
```

then you will see that all values are stored correctly.

Answer (score -1):

The items of array contains string and string in json can be represented in following ways :

[image]

Your inner object contains the hexadecimal digits equivalent for those special characters (Unicode Character) present in innerjson. (e.g. \u00a4 represents ¤ )

Reference http://www.json.org

Comment: The answer is misleading. The JSON string `innerJson` does not use Unicode escapes at all. It is the `description` method of the `innerObject` that uses Unicode escapes (as I commented above).